# Dragon Age 2 Hawke dealing little to no damage

Tags: dragon-age-2

I have exactly the same problem as [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18164/in-dragon-age-ii-hawke-is-no-longer-dealing-damage-and-only-getting-missed-or#18546) and also tried [this solution](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18164/in-dragon-age-ii-hawke-is-no-longer-dealing-damage-and-only-getting-missed-or/18243#18243):

> There is a good chance your Hawke doesnt have enough points invested in your main stat (warrior=str, mage=int, rogue=dex) which means your attack rating is too low.
>
> I suspect if you turn on damage popups youll see that you're just hitting for 1-3 damage

So I need to raise your main stat to solve the damage-hitting-problem.

By testing if it had to do with too few points in my Hawke's main stat=Str.

But even when I used a trainer to try and solve the damage-hitting-problem by maximizing my strength stat to 100, he still wouldn't deal any damage (I know this for sure, because I had enabled the 'Show damage numbers' option).

Has adding more points to your main stat solve the problem for you? Because I can't solve it in any way :(

I want to finish the story (at least the first time) without cheating or that only Hawke's companions are able to fight and I have a useless main character :S

Comment: DA:Origins is the DA1 expansion!

Comment: @David Actually it is the base game.  Awakenings is the expansion.  Either way, using a saved file editor from a completely different game clearly isn't going to work.

Comment: Ah okay, my bad :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Dragon Age II, Hawke is no longer dealing damage and only getting "Missed" or "Resisted"?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18164/in-dragon-age-ii-hawke-is-no-longer-dealing-damage-and-only-getting-missed-or)

Comment: Did you try posting a thread about this issue in the bioware technical support forums?

Comment: What difficulty are you playing at?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your elements? There could be a chance that you are using a fire weapon against a fire monster for example. This could mean that the damage reduction is negating your damage.

Have you tried changing weapons? I am playing a Rogue and am having no problem so far.

Comment: Good point, but already tried that to, not working..When status effects and minor details are enabled it tells me that every single attack of Hawke is a miss or is resisted.. I see now that the editing of my question also went wrong, haha. When searching for an answer for my problem, the first paragraph of my question is what someone else has tried (saved file editor). What I have tried is what I describe in the 2nd paragraph. Only thing I can think of now is that I maybe need a higher quality weapon that matches my stats?? Thanks for your input anyway :D

Comment: Also i looked around the web for any possible patches that already have come out to solve this problem, but there's nothing to be found.. :(

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your weapon? That happened to me too, and when I was just about to freak out, I checked my weapon, and saw it had 1 star.  I went and bought a new one from the Black Emporium and it worked.  Remember, 3 stars is average for your level, 1 is awful, and 5 is best (and often not yet attainable).  Make sure that you have a good weapon.

Also, the normal attack is pretty weak, even with a good weapon. Use some of the abilities.

And if you are a rogue, two weapons is usually better than one. At least in my opinion.

Comment: If you don't know, the Black Emporium is DLC.

Answer (score 0):

Well If you are a Warrior, then I may be able to help, because, when I played as Warrior and picked the Reaver as my specialization suddenly enemies resisted all of my attacks. I resolved the issue by using the cheat code that makes my Warrior level 2 again. Using the code fixed the resistance issue as long as I don't use the Reaver specialization.

That's the good news, the bad news are that if you have a customized appearance of Hawke and you want to keep it use the older save if you have one, because the code changes your appearance to the default one (the one that's in the game trailer). But that is your own choice.

Comment: It does work. Using the code fixed the resistance issue as long as I don't use the Reaver specialization. That's the good news, the bad news are that if you have a customized appearance of Hawke and you want to keep it use the older save if you have one, because the code changes your appearance to the default one (the one that's in the game trailer). But that is your own choice.